# Having issue with slow timestamp script as well as required to excluded Sheet 1 & Sheet 2

Tags: javascript, performance, dataframe, google-apps-script, time

I have a timestamp script is slow a bit also am unable to figure out how to exclude specific sheets ( Sheet 1 & Sheet 2 )

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  var row = e.range.getRow(); 
  var col = e.range.getColumn(); 
  var startRow = 2; 
  // var colName1 = 3; 
  // var colTime1 = 1; 
  // var colName2 = 09; 
  // var colTime2 = 11; 
  // var colName3 = 15; 
  // var colTime3 = 13; 
  // var colName4 = 21; 
  // var colTime4 = 22; 
  if(col == 3 && row >= startRow){ 
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1).setValue(new Date()); 
  } 
  if (col == 09 && row >= startRow){ 
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,11).setValue(new Date()); 
  } 
  if (col == 15 && row >= startRow){ 
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,13).setValue(new Date()); 
  } 
  if (col == 21 && row >= startRow){ 
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,22).setValue(new Date()); 
  } 
}
```

Looking for your kind help

Thanks

Comment: Please, could you provide more details on it and cleanup comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  var excl=['Sheet1','Sheet2'];
  var sh=e.range.getSheet(); 
  if(excl.indexOf(sh.getName())==-1 && e.range.rowStart>1) {
    var dt=new Date();
    if(e.range.columnStart==3)sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1).setValue(dt); 
    if(e.range.columnStart==9)sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,11).setValue(dt); 
    if(e.range.columnStart==15)sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,13).setValue(dt); 
    if(e.range.columnStart==21)sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,22).setValue(dt);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, thanks for kind response, but still slow as am running almost 20 tab in one sheet using the same timestamp scrips, anticipate your kind response and help

Comment: sometimes 10 of them were active at the same time

Comment: i have no idea why the last condition was not working as well if(e.range.columnStart==21)sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,22).setValue(dt);

Comment: In my experience 10 users with an onEdit() is probably not going to work reliably

Comment: trust me today i run it again and still slow? is there any way to make it a bit faster ? Thx

Comment: I doubt it. It's possible to have problems with onEdit with only a single user.  If you have a lot of users or some one making rapid edits it's fairly easy for the trigger to miss one.  I hardly ever use then and when I don't I'm patient with them and give the program plently of time to transition.  There advantages and disadvantages for running on a server.  This is a disadvantage.